# Why can't i change the content of a constant char pointer in C?

Tags: c

```
char* const p="C language\n";
printf("%s", p);
*p = "Change";
printf("%s", p);
```

Expected to print something like:

```
C language
Change
```

Comment: What type does `*p` have? What about `"Change"`?

Comment: The answer lies in your question: **constant**.

Comment: You need `p = "Change";` but it is `const` and cannot be re-assigned.

Comment: When trying to compile your code I see this warning

`warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`, that is because *p is a char which in C language is an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's `const char* p = "C language";`, not `char* const`. They have different meanings: `const char* p` means that the chars to which `p` points to, cannot be modified; while `char* const p` means that the pointer `p` itself cannot be modified.
2. `*p = "Change";` is not the correct way to change string's content. Even when the string is not read-only. One way to modify a string's content is to use: `strcpy(p, "Change")`
3. You cannot modify string literals because they are read-only by definition. *However*, you can declare "char arrays", and they can be modified:

   ```c
   char s[] = "C language";
   printf("%s\n", s);
   strcpy(s, "Change");
   printf("%s\n", s);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to change what `printf( "%s", p );` prints:

1. Change where p points to: `p = ...`. This does not work as p is a *constant* pointer.
2. Change the contents of the memory p points to. With `*p = ...` you change the one character at address p. If you want to change the string *starting* at address p, you need one of the many functions from `<string>`, or `sprintf()`, or similar. However, in this case that would not work either, because the memory occupied by string literals (`"C language\n"`, which p points to in your example) is read-only as well.

Hint: `char p[20] = "C language\n";` defines 20 bytes of *writeable* memory *initialized* to the value of the string literal.